# Height for expand form of drop down list

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, kendo-ui

I have a kendo ui drop down list and i want to set the height for the expanded list (red block in picture) to 500px.

What component do i need to edit to achive this? [image]

Comment: Can you share demo of your code or JSFiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Kendo UI documentation](http://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/dropdowns/) I believe you should change the `max-height` property on the `kendo-popup .k-popup kendo-list .k-list-scroller` element which by default is set to `200px`.

However I suggest you exclude the custom HTML elements from the CSS selector and use something like this instead:

```
.k-popup .k-list-scroller{
    max-height: 300px;
}
```

Comment: thanks for answer but in the docs i am find this [docs for height property kendo ui](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/dropdownlist#configuration-height) and for me help this. In dropDownList config i am write this `k-height='300'`

Comment: great! glad I could help you find what you needed.